# ES5 Javascript map through objects in array, then change the object key by group

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object, I tried to add one more word the object key, but having trouble with it, please check my data and expect output and the code I tried below:

Trying to get output like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    'name_A': Joe,
    'year_A': 2019,
    'saving_A': 0,
    'member_A': false,
    'group:_A': "A"
  },
  {
    'name_B': Amy,
    'year_B': 2019,
    'saving_B': 0,
    'member_B': false,
    'group_B': "B"
  },
  {
    'name_C': Bob,
    'year_C': 2019,
    'saving_C': 0,
    'member_C': true,
    'group_C': "C"
  }
];
```

Here's my code:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Joe',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: false,
    group: "A"
  },
  {
    name: 'Amy',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: false,
    group: "B"
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: true,
    group: "C"
  }
];
const filter = data.reduce((acc, key) => {
  const groupName = key.group;
  const obj = {};
  if (key.member === false) {
    const nodeId = key.nodeId + groupName;
    obj.nodeId = key.nodeId;
    obj.year = key.year;
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(filter)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you trying to change those? You wont be able to index them directly since they are still in an array. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Would you mind describing WHY you are trying to accomplish this?

Comment: `key.isYearToDate`??

Comment: Sorry it's Key.member === true, then the return object array. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using reduce:

```js
const data = [
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      year: 2019,
      saving: 0,
      member: false,
      group: "A"
    },
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      year: 2019,
      saving: 0,
      member: false,
      group: "B"
    },
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      year: 2019,
      saving: 0,
      member: true,
      group: "C"
    }
  ];

  let result = data.map(el => {
      const group = el.group
      return Object.keys(el).reduce((a, i) => {
          a[`${i}_${group}`] = el[i]
          return a
      }, {})
  })

  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to resolve this issue:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Joe',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: false,
    group: "A"
  },
  {
    name: 'Amy',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: false,
    group: "B"
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    year: 2019,
    saving: 0,
    member: true,
    group: "C"
  }
];

const format = arr => arr.map(el => {
  return Object.keys(el).reduce((accum, key) => {
    accum[`${key}_${el.group}`] = el[key];
    return accum;
  }, {});
});

console.log(format(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is a mix between the function `map` and function `reduce`.

The function `map` for converting the current objects to the desired structure, and the function `reduce` to concatenate the `group` with the current keys.

```js
const data = [  {    name:'Joe',                          year: 2019,                          saving: 0,                          member: false,                          group:"A"                          },                          {                          name: 'Amy',                          year: 2019,                          saving:0,                          member: false,                          group: "B"                          },                          {                          name:'Bob',                          year: 2019,                          saving: 0,                          member: true,                          group:"C"                          }                          ];
let result = data.map(({group, ...rest}) => Object.entries(rest).reduce((a, [k, v]) => Object.assign(a, {[`${k}_${group}`]: v}), {[`group_${group}`]: group}));

console.log(result);
```